# Duda sobre posicionamiento flotante

Tags: css

Buenas quisiera que me aclaren el siguiente problema. En si el posicionamiento flotante lo tengo bastante entendido, pero he estado probando el siguiente ejemplo.

```css
.contenedor {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hijo1,
.hijo2,
.hijo3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.hijo1 {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.hijo2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.hijo3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="hijo1">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hijo2">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hijo3">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
  <p>Hola como estan gente, espero que muy bien. Saludos</p>
</div>
```

Cuando las cajas no tienen contenido no hay ningún problema, ya que si posiciono la primera caja como flotante la segunda caja se pone por debajo de él, la cosa cambia cuando le agrego los h1 para hacerlo más indicativo y ocurre que si, si que la segunda caja se pone debajo de la primera pero NO en su totalidad y encima el h1 se queda fuera de el. Mi duda es a que se debe? ¿Porque el H1 de la segunda caja no es ocultado y se queda ahí afuera si está dentro de la caja? Espero me puedan explicar, gracias.

Comment: No me queda claro tu duda.

Comment: El numero dos se muestra, no se supone que si la primera caja "roja" esta flotando, la siguiente caja "verde" debe estar por debajo de él? pero estas cajas tienen un <h1> en su interior, si esta dentro de la caja por que se muestra como lo en la imagen?. La segunda caja se pone por detrás pero el numero "2" que es un <h1> esta como fuera de él o mejor dicho porque da ese resultado como si lo estuviese. Espero haber aclarado mejor.

Comment: Pero me parece que solo ocupas indicarle la posición al elemento que haces flotar, es decir: position: absolute. Cuando tenga algo de tiempo tratare de responder si nadie lo ha hecho

Comment: A que te refieres con flotante .. por que si quieres colocar un div por encima de otro lo que tienes que usar es Z-index https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Hola, buenas. Según leí sobre el posicionamiento flotante si posiciono la primera caja, la segunda se pone por debajo de la primera que esta flotando a la izquierda, tapando su contenido. A eso quiero llegar, en este caso no lo hace... y encima sobresale parte de la segunda caja. Simplemente quiero entender el ¿porque? pasa eso. Gracias.

Comment: Ronald Probaste ponerle position absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu pregunta, es **¿Por qué sucede?**, la respuesta es simple:

**Se debe a que los elementos flotados afectan los textos que no estén flotados**, es decir, pueden afectar a los elementos bloques como div, p, section, etc, pero **para los "textos" que están alrededor en cajas no flotadas estos se van a comportar como si estuvieran siendo repelidos por un magneto de carga contraria**.

Prueba a sacar el texto del h1, dejalo vacio y a este ponle algun estilo y verás que se comporta como esperas.

En el ejemplo que nos compartes, si bien el contenedor del 2, sube a ocupar el espacio dejado por el contenedor 1, el número que es un texto "no-flotado" al entrar en contacto con el elemento flotado original, se ve repelido. **De hecho "float" originalmente era usada para hacer composiciones como esta:** [MozzilaDev - Imagen Flotada](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats#frame_Playable_code).

Ahora si lo que estás haciendo es solo jugar y experimentar, no pasa nada, pero si estás tratando de sobreponer elementos y jugar con las capas de visibilidad, prueba mejor con **position: absolute;** como te recomendaron antes. Y **z-index** para controlar qué elemento está debajo de qué y no tendrás problemas de este tipo.

Éxitos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, el cuarto párrafo fue clave para porfín entender el funcionamiento completo de los float. De nuevo muchas gracias!!

Comment: De nada! Para eso estamos en la comunidad.